# Use Mod Rewrite to change site URLs

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Im pretty new to Apache's mod_rewrite and I'm trying to change how my URLs are displayed in the address bar. For instance I want

- www.example.com/index.php

to be

- www.example.com/home

and

- www.example.com/products.php

to be

- www.example.com/products

and so forth. So far I have this in mind but it's not working

```
RewriteRule ^home$  /index.php [L]
```

Comment: You may push the gas pedal, but it's meaningless if the engine isn't turned on. https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/home/$1 [R=301]

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/products/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can either put this on httpd.conf in apache or in .htaccess file.

`L` means - Last - stop processing rules

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Edit the *.htaccess* file contents as:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

This will redirect an url like this: *example.com/any_path.php* to *example.com/any_path*. To be precise, you are removing the .php extension from any PHP file.

Note:

- For specific url, replace `([^\.]+)` in the `RewriteRule` with the text.
- Specify a correct path for `RewriteBase` in case you are using a subdirectory.
- mod_rewrite should be turned on for your server system. Google a bit for turning on mod_rewrite in your system.